# node myapp.js > myapp_error.log 2>&1 equivalent when is starting as service

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, error-handling, systemctl

A simple testing app called `myapp`:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const json_encode = require('json_encode');

//emulate a real error
var wrong;
var test = json_encode(wrong);
//TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined at json_encode...
```

If I try to save `myapp_error.log` for `myapp` from command line I use:

```
node myapp2.js > myapp_error.log 2>&1
//myapp_error.log is created and I can read the error logged
```

I need to do the same but if I starting myapp as service in `/etc/systemd/system` like

```
systemctl start myapp
```

The service (tested and running ok):

```
[Unit]
Description=myapp

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/myapp/myapp.js
Restart=my_username
User=nobody
Group=www-data
Environment=PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/myapp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have tried:

`ExecStart=/path/to/myapp/myapp.js > myapp_error.log 2>&1` (this do nothing)

also tried:

`systemctl start myapp > myapp_error.log 2>&1` (this write a empty file `myapp_error.log` in  `/etc/systemd/system`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[Service]` block in your unit file has options for stdout/stderr logs:

```
StandardOutput=append:/path/to/stdout.log
StandardError=append:/path/to/stderr.log
```

Edit (from comments discussion):

Running `node` itself was also missing:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node /path/to/myapp/myapp.js
```

Systemd doesn't know what to do with a JS file, so we need to call the correct interpreter first.

Comment: added and tested ... but nothing .. I have now 2 empty files `stdout.log` and `stderr.log` in myapp directory (y have added `/path/to/myapp/stderr.log`)

Comment: Tested also with `ExecStart=/path/to/myapp/myapp.js > myapp_error.log 2>&1`  and `ExecStart=/path/to/myapp/myapp.js` but still nothing ... (only the two new empty files) I am missing something?

Comment: (to be sure) I have tested again in command line with `node myapp2.js > myapp_error.log 2>&1`  and `myapp_error.log` is ok is writting the error

Comment: If you stop the service, start it again, and check the journal, are the logs in there? What's your systemd version?

Comment: systemd 245 (245.4-4ubuntu3.17)
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid

Comment: the last log in journal is 2 hours before when I have made a typo in my path `Dec 03 05:07:49 myapp.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory` ... I repeat this is not from now is two hours before (now in my country is 07:04 hours)

Comment: If you change your ExecStart to `/usr/bin/node /path/to/app.js` (or wherever your `node` executable is) does that get things working?

Comment: YES SR! with `/usr/bin/node` IT WORK. Thank You

Comment: Hah! You're welcome, I completely overlooked that the first few times I read your unit file. I'll add that to my answer as well.